# Find a JS function/string in Firebug script console

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

I am using Firebug to debug 3 lines of JS I have written, but the framework I am using generates 10k lines of JS code.

And I end up finding those 3 lines manually.

Is there a way to search for a string/function in the script console of Firebug?

Any work around?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should just be a search box in the upper-right hand part of the console

Answer (score 0):

There is a little search box at the top right corner of the firebug window.